# VSCode: Does anyone else have an issue with the Source Control tab not showing changes made to Apex classes / triggers?

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforcedx, visualstudiocode, github

I'm new to Visual Studio Code, and have followed directions I found on the web for setting up a project with manifest, and then authorizing a sandbox, as well as connecting to a GitHub remote repo.

I've been trying to do some testing / playing around with branches, to test a branching strategy I would like my team to adopt, but I can't seem to test effectively when editing actual Apex code that I pulled from the initial "Retrieve source from manifest in org" step, off of the package.xml file, because the edits I make to a trigger for example, doesn't show as a change in Source Control tab on the left of the UI - so I can't stage or commit anything unless I do something like edit the readme file, which is great to test the actual branch strat "barebones" but it doesn't give me confidence that I can work on actual code in my sfdc environment - has anyone ran into similar issues?

[image: Screenshot shows that README2 is an edit I can commit, but README3 isn't detected]

Comment: Anyone have any ideas? I can elaborate on the issue if need be.

Comment: How did you create this scenario? It looks like your salesforce files are not in your repo which is why git is not tracking them? "SFIT-repo" is the name of your git repo but none of the files are under that structure. GIT only tracks what's in it's repo. In this case, it looks like you have a blank repo you cloned with just a readme files. If you move an apex class to be under it, you'll see a "new" change that you added a file is my guess